# Semi-lattices whose Hasse Diagrams are trees after transitive reduction?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders, integer-lattices

Is there a name or anything else known for a semi-lattice whose Hasse Diagram becomes a tree after applying transitive reduction?

Trying to find more about it since it comes up in an optimization [problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/147773/optimizing-a-sum-of-matrix-chains) (need to find the optimal way to distribute * over + in a sum containing terms with this kind of lattice structure)

For instance consider the following subsets of real line ordered by subset inclusion:
$$[0, 5], [1,3], [2,3], [1,2], [3,5]$$

Its Hasse Diagram:

[image]

Two gray lines disappear after transitive reduction, so the result is a tree.

I found [this paper](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/libkin/papers/dm95.pdf) on semi-lattices whose diagrams are trees, but that's a much more restrictive set, doesn't include my example.

** edit ** the paper doesn't define "diagram", but we assume the same as Hasse Diagram from wikipedia, it sounds like it's saying these semi-lattices would be called "convex semi-lattices"

[image]

Comment: I thought the term "Hasse diagram" referred to the diagram that remains **after** "transitive reduction".

Comment: @bof oh...interesting point. The paper I linked doesn't define "diagram" so I can't tell if it applies transitive reduction or not :/

Comment: According to [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) the Hasse diagram of a finite poset is a drawing of its transitive reduction.

Comment: @bof I see thanks for the clarification....in that case it sounds like the paper is suggesting that these semilattices are "convex semi-lattices"

Answer (score 2):

In general, the only diagrammatic representation for a partially ordered set (poset) one cares for is the Hasse diagram. Drawing more (valid) edges is redundant, as the poset will still be the same and the diagram will be more cluttered. As such, all diagrammatic characterizations of a poset apply to its Hasse diagram.